# What's the fastest way to install Postgresql on Wind River 7.0?

Tags: linux, rpm, postgresql

I'm new to bare-bones Linux systems and need to install postgres on a wind river Linux distribution. My plan was to install yum and then use yum to install the postgres rpm.

I've tried to install yum but am getting this following error:
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

```
No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.3 (default, Dec 21 2015, 05:03:08) 
[GCC 4.9.1]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

There is only one version of Python on the system and it is Python 2.7.3 and is located at usr/lib/python2.7.

It seems like this error is usually due to multiple version of python being installed, yet I only have one. Does this mean that the version of yum I've installed(3.4.3) is for a newer version of python?

Should I continue trying to install yum and then postgres or use a different method to install postgres i.e. manually with the rpm files found [here](http://yum.postgresql.org/9.5/).

Comment: Is wind river a RedHat clone, or something else?

Comment: @thrig I think it's based on RedHat but modified for embedded systems, not 100% sure though

Comment: Hmm, RedHat has shipped with `yum` for a few years now, so if the wind river folks have removed that, then it might be easier to `rpm -U *.rpm` the necessary files.

Answer (score 0):

Wind River's Linux is meant for build-once-then-ship kind of images, which don't play very well with package management like yum or apt. It commonly also doesn't work very well with things that want to write to the filesystem after writing the image to your embedded device, like database servers -- so they probably don't have it for you to install (and installing from yum is very likely going to fail due to binary incompatibilities).

If you really need PostgreSQL, ask yourself if Wind River Linux is the right tool for the job (my guess is that it isn't). If you still think so, you'll have to compile PostgreSQL from source.